# How does NMAP know that the device is a F5 load balancer

Tags: f5

I was just wondering how does nmap guess that the IP address is a load balancer?
Im scanning on the IP address on a Virtual IP on a F5 and it correctly identified that its an F5 appliance.

how does it know?

regards,

Jon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NMAP uses quite a number of observable features to guess a device's operating system and details.  Easily seen for local hosts is the ethernet address, which has 24-bit Organisationally Unique Identifier.  However, these are only available for local hosts and also can be faked by many methods, and tell you very little more than the manufacturer.  So NMAP uses many other things as well, which the operating system usually choose, such as settings for ID fields, flags and so on, and users have over time collected the fingerprints of many different operating systems.  A few manufacturers contribute also.

From NMAP's manual page:

> One of Nmap's best-known features is remote OS detection using TCP/IP
>   stack fingerprinting. Nmap sends a series of TCP and UDP packets to
>   the remote host and examines practically every bit in the responses.
>   After performing dozens of tests such as TCP ISN sampling, TCP options
>   support and ordering, IP ID sampling, and the initial window size
>   check, Nmap compares the results to its nmap-os-db.  database of more
>   than 2,600 known OS fingerprints

Comment: In addition to nmap-os-db, the nmap-service-probes file shows a bunch of F5 specific tests results in case you're interested: https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/nmap-service-probes.

Comment: With every major release of BIG-IP, F5 sends the results of nmap -O -sV -T4 -d [target] to NMAP so they can update the OS database. F5 uses an customized version of CentOS so it used to be mistaken for that or RedHat Ent.  https://nmap.org/cgi-bin/submit.cgi?corr-os

Comment: If only all manufacturers were so collaborative!  Added postscript to answer.

Answer (score 3):

nmap probes the target machine for open TCP/UDP ports. When it finds an open
port, it sends "probe" data to that port and sees what, if anything, comes
back. This "probe" data that nmap sends depends on the well-known service that
is usually expected to be available at that port. For example, if nmap detects
that tcp/80 is open, nmap then sends an HTTP request as the probe data.

The final report that nmap generates is consolidated from the responses that it
gets back in response to the probes sent to various ports.

Run nmap with the '-d' flag to make it display what it is doing

E.g. right now in my home network, my computer detected that my broadband router
is a tp-link device running dd-wrt:

```
desktop:~$ nmap -A -d 192.168.1.1

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-02-12 16:02 IST
PORTS: Using top 1000 ports found open (TCP:1000, UDP:0, SCTP:0)
...
...
Initiating Connect Scan at 16:02
Scanning 192.168.1.1 [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 192.168.1.1
Discovered open port 23/tcp on 192.168.1.1
Discovered open port 53/tcp on 192.168.1.1
Completed Connect Scan at 16:02, 0.11s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Overall sending rates: 9200.99 packets / s.
Initiating Service scan at 16:02
Scanning 3 services on 192.168.1.1
Completed Service scan at 16:02, 6.02s elapsed (3 services on 1 host)
NSE: Script scanning 192.168.1.1.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 2) scan.
Initiating NSE at 16:02
...
...
Not shown: 997 closed ports
Reason: 997 conn-refused
PORT   STATE SERVICE REASON  VERSION
23/tcp open  telnet  syn-ack DD-WRT telnetd (DD-WRT v24-sp2 std 03/25/13 r21061)
53/tcp open  domain  syn-ack dnsmasq 2.45
| dns-nsid: 
|_  bind.version: dnsmasq-2.45
80/tcp open  http    syn-ack DD-WRT milli_httpd
|_http-favicon: Unknown favicon MD5: 9C003F40E63DF95A2B844C6B61448310
| http-methods: 
|_  Supported Methods: GET POST
|_http-server-header: httpd
|_http-title: tplink (build 21061) - Info
Service Info: Host: tplink; OS: Linux; Devices: WAP, broadband router; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel
Final times for host: srtt: 11547 rttvar: 122  to: 100000
...
...
```

See also this link https://nmap.org/book/vscan.html

Footnote: I know of at least one case where running nmap (with some specific
options) against a device manufactured by certain well known network equipment
vendor actually crashed the device in production. So although it is a great tool
for testing and validating devices, running nmap in a production network and
targeting the network infrastructure should be strongly discouraged.

Comment: There is a contrary opinion, which is that if a tool such as NMAP might conceivably interfere with your network, it's a good idea to run tests periodically to ensure you know what might be possible from unauthorised scans.